# Target Paragraph Inside Table

Tags: jquery

I feel a bit stupid, I looked stackoverflow over and over again, found much help but nothing worked. I can not target the following html:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p class="dialog">More Infos</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

so that my hover effect works. I tried so many combinations, this is one of them:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('table tr td .dialog').contenthover({
        overlay_background:'#000',
        overlay_opacity:0.8
        });
    });
```

I also tried to use the .find function.
The hover effect works if I just target p.dialog and remove the table structure in the html, but I need the table !

Comment: I see no issues with your selector `$('table tr td .dialog')`. Are you getting any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Have you tried `$('table tr td .dialog').on("mouseover",function(){` ?

Comment: no errors at all, hmm I also find it strange, especially because it works if I just use `<p class="dialog">More Infos</p>` and target `$('.dialog')` !

Comment: There's no reason, given the code that you're showing, that either selector would fail to find that element. It's something to do with this non-jQuery `contenthover` function that you're calling, or something else. Please review how to create a [mcve].

Comment: well Mike McCaughan I guess that was the answer I was looking for since you identified the problem (I have read your link before), but didn't knew that the contenthover function could be the problem (I though it was a jQuery part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is three things that I see.

1- A non-jQuery method : `.contenthover`
2- Some non-CSS attributes : `overlay_...`
3- CSS changes are done with `.css()` method.

Try this:

```
$('table tr td .dialog').on("mouseover",function(){
    $(this).css({"background":"#000","opacity":0.8});
});
```

Should work.